# Unable to add a new field to a content type, widget drop down not working

Tags: drupal-7

These are my first steps with drupal.

I have created a taxonomy hierarchy for my articles and now I am trying to add a new field to the content type "Article" and "Media" so the content admin can assign a "category" to his new content.

So I've been to Structure > Content Types > Article > Manage Fields
Then "Add new field" with :

```
1- Label = Category
2- Name = "field_category
3- Field = "Term reference"
**4- Automatically changes to "Select list" but I am unable to see the drop down list options. Clicking the list doesn't do anything, I couldn't select Autocomplete or any other value I've seen on forums & tutorials. Using firebug I could see the options are there, but the list doesn't show up.**
```

This is happening with all types of fields, even with text fields, the most basic one.
Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem across multiple sites. I don't seem to be able to add a new field to an existing content type. Keep getting this error:

`Add new field: you need to select a widget.`

Answer (score 5):

As glumbo mentioned, the problem here is caused by **jQuery 1.7 update**. As of jQuery 1.6 DOM properties should be accessed using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function. 
There is an [open issue](http://drupal.org/node/1448494) with some **hotfix solution**:

You need to replace **.attr()** jQuery function call with **.prop()** in `/modules/field_ui/field_ui.js` at following lines:

```
100:      $(this).html(html).attr('disabled', disabled ? 'disabled' : '');
253:      $(ajaxElements).attr('disabled', true);
```

Please note that this fix modifies a Drupal core module and you'll probably want to use a patch (Dries would kill the kitty anyway:).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with jquery update. If you are using jquery 1.7 you will get this problem

Comment: Any idea how to fix this while still using jQuery 1.7?